# Responsive layout not scaling properly in iPhone 7 and iPad 7

Tags: ios, iphone, css, ipad, autolayout

The front end and responsive design of following page is working properly in all mobile browsers except iPhone 7 and iPad 7.

http://tinglabs.in/chennai/tingau/index-ios-resp.html

I have tried scaling it properly through the following meta tags but it still doesn't work

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
```

Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1.0">
```